# Linq select query that uses prior property in calculated field

Tags: c#, linq, select

I have a couple of properties that are calculated out in a LINQ query in the select portion of the query.  I need to use the results from these properties to perform another calculation in a separate property.

Currently how I am doing this

```
var query = data
    .Select(model => new 
    {
        SomeProperty1 = model.Sum(x => x.Foo),
        SomeProperty2 = model.Sum(x => x.Bar),
        SomeProperty3 = model.Sum(x => x.Bar) == 0 ? 0 : 
            model.Sum(x => x.Foo) / model.Sum(x => x.Bar)
    };
```

Was wondering if there was some way I could do this

```
var query = data
    .Select(model => new 
    {
        SomeProperty1 = model.Sum(x => x.Foo),
        SomeProperty2 = model.Sum(x => x.Bar),
        SomeProperty3 = this.SomeProperty2 == 0 ? 0 : 
            this.SomeProperty1 / this.SomeProperty2
    };
```

Examples are greatly shortened for brevity.  In my actual query the calculations are a lot more lengthy.

I believe this can be done in the `get` portion of the property in the model, but was just wondering if it could be done like shown above in the linq query.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot refer to newly created object in object initializer (C# Specification 7.6.10.2), but you can introduce new query variables in LINQ query:

```
var query = from model in data
            let SomeProperty1 = model.Sum(x => x.Foo)
            let SomeProperty2 = model.Sum(x => x.Bar)
            select new {
                SomeProperty1,
                SomeProperty2,
                SomeProperty3 = SomeProperty2 == 0 ? 0 : SomeProperty1 / SomeProperty2
            };
```

Also keep in mind that integer division is used when both divident and divisor are integers.

Comment: A little more verbose than I wanted, but strides better than the current state of my query.  I will accept this as the answer once it lets me.

Comment: @DavidLee benefit is that sum will be calculated only once here

Comment: Can you nest these variables?

Comment: Sorry should have included an example: let SomeProperty2 = model.Sum(x => x.Bar) + SomeProperty2

Comment: @DavidLee what do you mean by nesting? You can refer to previously defined query variables, i.e. you can use `SomeProperty1` in `SomeProperty2` calculation